# How to use Fortran to write a specific GNUPLOT command with special characters in to a txt file?

Tags: awk, plot, fortran, gnuplot

I would like to write GNUPLOT commands in to a txt file using Fortran, I can do it for most of the simple commands, but I have problem writing commands that contain special characters or AWK commands.

Assume I have a three column input file. First column is used to set the color of the points that their coordinates are stored in column 2 and 3.

For example, my input file called "Input.dat" is as follows:

```
blue 1 1
red  2 1
red  3 0
blue 4 1
red  5 1
blue 6 1
```

I use the following txt file which contains GNUPLOTs commands and I use to plot  my input file.

GNUPLOT.txt:

```
plot "< awk '{if($1 == \"blue\") print}' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "blue" w p pt 7, \
     "< awk '{if($1 == \"red\") print}' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "red" w p pt 7
pause -1
```

I need to create this input txt file using Fortran commands but I can not!
Would you please let me know how to create a txt file like GNUPLOT.txt using Fortran commands?

I have used following commands with no luck:

```
write( 'GNUPLOT.txt', * )'set pointsize 3'
write( 'GNUPLOT.txt', * )'plot "< awk '{if($1 == \"blue\") print}' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "blue" w p pt 7, \'
write( 'GNUPLOT.txt', * )'"< awk '{if($1 == \"red\") print}' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "red" w p pt 7'
write( 'GNUPLOT.txt', * )'pause -1'
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
write( 11, * ) 'set pointsize 3'
write( 11, * ) 'plot "< awk ''{if($1 == \"blue\") print}'' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "blue" w p pt 7, \'
write( 11, * ) '"< awk ''{if($1 == \"red\") print}'' Input.dat" u 2:3 t "red" w p pt 7'
write( 11, * ) 'pause -1'
```

Inside the string you must double the character you use to delimit the string.

For example,

```
print *,''''
end
```

will print just `'`.

Comment: The use of a character literal as the output unit will be problematic too.

Comment: @IanH Sure, I just copied that. I assume everyone knows how to use output units.